# Unexpected behavior of 'fread()', 'fwrite()' and 'fseek()'

Tags: c, stdio

I wrote a simple C program, which takes a `.txt` file and replaces all spaces with hyphens. However, the program enters an infinite loop and the result is endless array of hyphens.

This is the input file:

```
a b c d e f
```

This is the file after the process crashes:

```
a----------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------... (continues thousands of times)...
```

I guess the reason in unexpected behavior of `fread()`, `fwrite()` and `fseek()`, or my misunderstanding of these functions. This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXBUF 1024

int main(void) {

    char buf[MAXBUF];
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    char hyph = '-';

    printf("Enter file name:\n");
    fgets(buf, MAXBUF, stdin);
    sscanf(buf, "%s\n", buf);   /* trick to replace '\n' with '\0' */

    if ((fp = fopen(buf, "r+")) == NULL) {
        perror("Error");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fread(&c, 1, 1, fp);

    while (c != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR); /* rewind file position indicator to the position of the ' ' */
            fwrite(&hyph, 1, 1, fp); /* write '-' instead */
        }
        fread(&c, 1, 1, fp); /* read next character */
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: What OS are you using? I compiled and run you program and it goes into an endless loop due to not checking the EOF properly (as stated in Joe's answer), however it does not create an endless stream of hyphens.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

1) You should be checking that fread returns the number of items you requested, e.g. that you get a 1 back.

2) You should then be checking feof(fp), not comparing the character you read to EOF.  This will tell you if your read returned less/no items because of EOF or some other reason.

Comment: You are right, but it didn't fix the bug. What fixed it, is that I added after the line `fwrite(&hyph, 1, 1, fp);`, the line `fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_CUR);`. It seems that `fwrite()` doesn't advance the file position indicator at all contrary to what I thought. So I did it manually. Now it works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If `fwrite` doesn't advance the file position, something is wrong. From [the opengroup page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fwrite.html): The file-position indicator for the stream (if defined) shall be advanced by the number of bytes successfully written.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems...

Check what types the standard C library functions return and what that return value means.
The std C library defines `EOF` as the *integer* -1.  Since the full character set is 256 characters and the type char can hold from 0 to 255 (256 diff values) it was necessary to make `EOF` an integer.

With all that bluster aside...  You're also checking for `EOF` incorrectly.

The problems, spelled out:

You should check the return value from `fread`

```
if( fread(&c, 1, 1, fp) != 1 )
{
    // Handle the error
}

// `EOF` is the integer -1.  It will not fit in a char.  So, your while loop becomes endless unless you get a -1 in the data stream

// The "correct" way to do what you want to do is using the stdlib function feof(fp)
while( !feof( fp ) )
{
    if (c == ' ')
    {
        // You should check the value returned by fseek for errors
        fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR); /* rewind file position indicator to the position of the ' ' */
        // You should check the value returned by fwrite for errors
        fwrite(&hyph, 1, 1, fp); /* write '-' instead */
    }

    if( fread(&c, 1, 1, fp) != 1 )
    {
        // Handle the error
    }
}
```

All of that said...  It is very inefficient to read a character at a time on modern systems.  Adapt your code to read a buffer full at a time and write the entire modified buffer out at once.

Comment: @JimR He should write `"-"` which is a `const char *` rather than `'-'` which is just a `const char`.

Comment: @jimR `hyph` is a `char`, however `&hyph` is a `char *`.  As such, you cannot replace `&hyph` with `'-'`.  `const char * ptr = &hyph;` and `const char * ptr = "-";` are valid syntaxes.  `const char * ptr = '-';` is not valid.

Comment: @DavidM.Syzdek: I'm niot arguing that.  It was part of his code before I came along.  I didn't correct it because he had worked around the problem with `&hyph` and I figured I buried him in enough information without mentioning that.  I really hesitated to mention the inefficiencies for the same reason but since I see that as a bigger long term issue ....

Answer (score 1):

The reason:

For files open for update (those which include a "+" sign), on which both input and output operations are allowed, the stream shall be flushed (fflush) or repositioned (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) before a reading operation that follows a writing operation. The stream shall be repositioned (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) before a writing operation that follows a reading operation (whenever that operation did not reach the end-of-file).

The solution:

You should add "fflush(fp);" after the fwrite line.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice this note in reference docs, and I was using the `r+b` mode extensively doing both fwrite+fread and it was working for me long time on many platforms (linux,mac,bsd,windows) (the file positions being updated as naively assumed by me), but one time I did fwrite content starting with zero and the code did fail on windows builds... took me whole day to find this small note. With explicit `fseek` ahead `fread` it works well again.